# CSS animation: Image going off screen makes page go to top

Tags: html, css, css-animations

This is making me crazy and I hope that someone can give me a simple solution.

So I have a app on my website that allows you to like or dislike Recipes. When disliking there is an animation sending the image to the left, when liking the animation sends the image to the right (based on the Tinder swiping).

On my laptop everything works fine, but when I load the website on my mobile phone after the left animation is done the page is going back to the top, making me scroll back down every time I like something.
The dislike button works just fine. And if I change the Yes animation to the exact same like the No, it works. So it's really something with that animation.

I think the issue is caused because the image goes out of the screen and it then loads back at the top. But I don't understand why it doesn't happen when going to the left and I can't find a good solution

```
@keyframes yes {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1) rotateZ(0deg);
    left: 0;
  }
  30% {
    transform: scale(1.05) rotateZ(0deg);
    left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(45deg);
    left: 400px;
  }
}
.animateYes {
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation: yes 0.6s linear;
}
.animateYes:before {
  transform: rotateZ(-35deg);
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/Zkwj970.png) no-repeat center 10px;
}

@keyframes no {
  0% {
    transform: rotateZ(360deg);
    right: 0;
  }
  30% {
    transform: scale(1.05) rotateZ(360deg);
    right: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(315deg);
    right: 400px;
  }
}
.animateNo {
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation: no 0.6s linear;
}
.animateNo:before {
  transform: rotateZ(35deg);
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/XqQZ4KR.png) no-repeat center 10px;
}
```

This is the website: http://ons-kookboek.atwebpages.com/test.html

I'm a beginner in everything about html and CSS and most of my website is copy paste from the internet without me understanding what it exactly does.

Comment: It's working fine on my IOS Safari (iPad 14.7.1). What phone/OS/browser are you using?

Comment: I'm guessing that is probably not due to the shown CSS at all, but rather due to how you trigger this functionality. You have link elements without a `href` attribute there, and on those apparently a `mousedown` handler - maybe the mobile device jumps to the top, because those links don't actually target anything. Those should not be links to begin with, but proper button elements.

Comment: I'm working with the Android 10 on a moto g7 play and chrome.

It isn't going to the top of the page if I copy paste the keyframe info from the no animation to the yes animation. So as far as my understanding that eliminates any kind of handler that i'm missing